# What is this geographical feature? (as seen in maps)

Tags: groundwater, land-surface, landscape

Can someone help me identify [this peculiar geographical feature I've noticed in satellite imagery](https://www.google.es/maps/@69.2125436,154.2942761,53057m/data=!3m1!1e3)?

[image: Satellite image of northern Russia]

This particular screenshot is from satellite imagery of northern Russia, however this kind of geography appears extremely common in the northernmost latitudes of both Russia, Canada, and the United States.

[The below image is from Alaska](https://www.google.es/maps/@70.4076467,-153.5539541,50130m/data=!3m1!1e3).

[image: Satellite image of northern Alaska].

I've always wondered how this landscape would be described. Is this marshland, or swamps, or something else in particular?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you put links to Google Maps in satellite view to take a look?

Comment: @Universal_learner Here are some coordinates you can type into Google Maps: 70.25917998274016, -153.35379817667732. This is roughly where the Alaska screenshot above was captured.

Comment: [Tundra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dark color of the water masses make me think they are [peatlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mire) in [tundra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tundra).

> Peatland is a terrestrial wetland ecosystem in which the production of
> organic matter exceeds its decomposition and a net accumulation of
> peat results.
>
> The largest known concentrations of peatland are **found in Canada and
> Alaska, Northern Europe and Western Siberia**, Southeast Asia, and parts
> of the Amazon basin, where more than 10% of the land area is covered
> with peatlands.

Source: [peatlands.org](https://peatlands.org/peatlands/)

Comment: I think you've nailed it! Thanks so much for answering this.